# node-postgres: parameterised insert query cached, failing on 2nd run

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm trying to run two parameterised insert queries using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres): the first one specifies the primary key column, the second doesn't.

The second query, even though doesn't specify the primary key column, fails saying there's a duplicate primary key.

My pg table:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  created_by int REFERENCES users,
  name text,
  logo text
);
```

Code that reproduces this issue:

```
var pg = require('pg');

var insertWithId = 'INSERT INTO teams(id, name, created_by) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id';
var insertWithoutId = 'INSERT INTO teams(name, created_by) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id';

pg.connect(process.env.POSTGRES_URI, function (err, client, releaseClient) {
  client.query(insertWithId, [1, 'First Team', 1], function (err, result) {
    releaseClient();

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log('first team created');
  });
});

pg.connect(process.env.POSTGRES_URI, function (err, client, releaseClient) {
  client.query(insertWithoutId, ['Second Team', 1], function (err, result) {
    releaseClient();

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

And output of running this:

```
first team created

{ [error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "teams_pkey"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 173,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23505',
  detail: 'Key (id)=(1) already exists.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'teams',
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: 'teams_pkey',
  file: 'nbtinsert.c',
  line: '406',
  routine: '_bt_check_unique' }
```

What I gather from reading the `node-postgres` source, parameterised queries are treated as prepared queries, which get cached if they reuse a `name` parameter; though from digging around it's source, it doesn't seem to think that my queries have a name property.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be avoided?

Comment: The first insert supplies a value for `id`, so the serial is not incremented. The serial still is `1`. The second insert does not supply a value for `id`, so the serial (=1) is used. Which is a duplicate. Best solution is to only use the second statement, and let the application use the returned `id`, if needed.

Comment: well I hadn't thought of that, after a bit of Googling, it looks like that is indeed the issue.. Turn your comment into an answer and I shall accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first insert supplies a value for `id`, so the serial is not incremented. The serial still is 1 after the first insert. The second insert does *not* supply a value for `id`, so the serial (=1) is used. Which is a duplicate. Best solution is to *only* use the second statement, and let the application use the returned id, if needed.

In short: don't interfere with serials.

---

If you need to correct the next value for a sequence, you can use something like the below statement.

```
SELECT setval('teams_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM teams) )
        ;
```